# pip install with flag "--index-url" and "--extra-index-url" from GitLab results in "ERROR: HTTP error 404 while getting"

Tags: python, pip, gitlab, python-module

We are using a private GitLab Enterprise installation for storing Python modules as described in the article [PyPI packages in the Package Registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/pypi_repository/) 
The following command was used inside containers to install the privately hosted packages:

```
pip install <package_name_01> <package_name_02> \
    --index-url https://<personal_access_token_name_package_01>:<personal_access_token_package_01>@gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id_package_01>/packages/pypi/simple \
    --extra-index-url https://<personal_access_token_name_package_02>:<personal_access_token_package_02>@gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id_package_02>/packages/pypi/simple
```

As seen in the example, we use packages from different GitLab projects. Therefore, we had to specify each GitLab project as `--index-url` and `--extra-index-url`. The showed solution was working but since a few days, we receive the following error:

```
pip install <package_name_01> <package_name_02> \
> --index-url https://<personal_access_token_name_package_01>:<personal_access_token_package_01>@gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id_package_01>/packages/pypi/simple \
> --extra-index-url https://<personal_access_token_name_package_02>:<personal_access_token_package_02>@gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id_package_02>/packages/pypi/simple
Looking in indexes: https://<personal_access_token_name_package_01>:****@gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id_package_01>/packages/pypi/simple, https://<personal_access_token_name_package_02>:****@gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id_package_02>/packages/pypi/simple
Collecting <package_name_01>
  ERROR: HTTP error 404 while getting https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id_package_01>/packages/pypi/files/55a5d545c01aee6ef5488cb18f9d19eee9d79XXXXXXX/<package_name_01>-0.0.18-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=55a5d545c01aee6ef5488cb18f9d19eee9d79XXXXXXX (from https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id_package_01>/packages/pypi/simple/<package_name_01>/) (requires-python:>=3.6)
ERROR: Could not install requirement <package_name_01>==0.0.18 from https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id_package_01>/packages/pypi/files/55a5d545c01aee6ef5488cb18f9d19eee9d79XXXXXXX/<package_name_01>-0.0.18-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=55a5d545c01aee6ef5488cb18f9d19eee9d79XXXXXXX because of HTTP error 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id_package_01>/packages/pypi/files/55a5d545c01aee6ef5488cb18f9d19eee9d79XXXXXXX/<package_name_01>-0.0.18-py3-none-any.whl for URL https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id_package_01>/packages/pypi/files/55a5d545c01aee6ef5488cb18f9d19eee9d79XXXXXXX/<package_name_01>-0.0.18-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=55a5d545c01aee6ef5488cb18f9d19eee9d79XXXXXXX (from https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id_package_01>/packages/pypi/simple/<package_name_01>/) (requires-python:>=3.6)
```

Installing the modules separately works however...

```
pip install <package_name_01> --index-url https://<personal_access_token_name_package_01>:<personal_access_token_package_01>@gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id_package_01>/packages/pypi/simple
pip install <package_name_02> --index-url https://<personal_access_token_name_package_02>:<personal_access_token_package_02>@gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id_package_02>/packages/pypi/simple
```

Does anyone have an idea what goes wrong here?

Comment: Can u just try the pip install with `-vvv` to possibly get more info

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in GitLab, wich needs to be resolved in the future.

Link to the official GitLab issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/371814

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in `pip` as of version 23.1. See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10902#issuecomment-1792415703.

I haven't tested exactly your example but I've successfully configured several extra indices with different tokens.

```
pip install \
--extra-index-url https://user1:token1@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/12345/packages/pypi/simple \
--extra-index-url https://user2:token2@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/23456/packages/pypi/simple \
--extra-index-url https://user3:token3@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/34567/packages/pypi/simple \
package3
```

This will install `package3` from the third private registry and `package1` and `package2` from the first and second private registries using different credentials for each.